# How to do jQuery autocomplete that passes a id and display name

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, get

I am new in php.I have a script that work fine.but the problem is that i want to pass the id of the name completed.

My input text:

```
<tr><td>Marital Status</td><td><input type="text" id="m_status"    
name="m_status" value="<?php echo $ddlMarital >0 ?    
$MartialArray[$ddlMarital] : '' ;?>"></td></tr>
```

Script:

```
$(function() {

     $( "#m_status" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'Getmstaus.php'
    });
```

Getmstaus.php:

```
<?php
include("include/connection.php");

$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

    //get matched data from skills table
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM m_status WHERE m_status LIKE   
   '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY m_status ASC");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data['name'] = $row['m_status'];
         $data['id'] = $row['m_id'];

    }


    echo json_encode($data);
```

Now I get `M_status name` and if i submit the form that `m_status` will submit.But i want to display `m_status` and while form submit i want to submit `m_id`.How can i do this?Please help me.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this Hope this will help you

```
    tr><td>Marital Status</td><td>
      <input type="text" id="m_status"    
        name="m_status" value="<?php echo $ddlMarital >0 ?    
        $MartialArray[$ddlMarital] : '' ;?>">
    </td>
   <input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="project-id">

    </tr>
```

**Script**

```
<script>



  $( function() {


    $( "#m_status" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: 'Getmstaus.php',

      select: function( event, ui ) {
     $('#project-id').val(ui.item.id);

        //return false;
      }
    })

  } );
  </script>
```

**Getmstaus.php:**

```
    <?php
    include("include/connection.php");

    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

        //get matched data from skills table
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM m_status WHERE m_status LIKE   
       '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY m_status ASC");
        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

 $data[] = array(
    "value" => $row['m_status',
    "id" => $row['m_id'],

);

        }


        echo json_encode($data);
```